LWC: Event Not Firing
For some reason, this does not generate an alert on the screen...
In orderTable.html...
<button onclick={cancelOrder}>Cancel Order</button>

In orderTable.js...
cancelOrder(event) {  
  console.log("hello"); //THIS FIRES
  this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('ordercancelled'));
}

In manageOrders.html...
<c-order-table onordercancelled={ordercancelledHandler}></c-order-table>

In manageOrders.js...
ordercancelledHandler() {  
  console.log("boom"); //THIS DOES NOT FIRE
}


Which event does work? Are you receiving the cancelOrder event? Please edit your question with more information

@NickC done. The child method fires (the button click handler). The parent method (in manageOrders.js) does not.

Might seem silly, but did you deploy both components latest versions to your org? Sometimes we save the file locally but forget to push it to the org. :)

Could you update your post with more of the JS file? Specifically the top level where you import/export/extend modules modules.
